# Query to include non-existent rows as 0 value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, left-join

Although there are a number of similar questions on SO, I could not find any answer that would give me the desired output.

Situation: table "purchaseorders" containing POs with various details. Example record:

```
| id | orderId | number | vendorNumber | grossValue | bookingYear |
|----|---------|--------|--------------|------------|-------------|
| 14 | 691     | 1      | 12345        | 152.43     | 2016        |
```

I want aggregate sums(grossValue) for specific vendors for the past 5 years, including 0 values.
Required output:

[image]

Current actual output:

[image]

My attempt at SQL:

```
SELECT po.bookingYear, IFNULL (sum(po.grossValue),0) FROM purchaseorder as po
LEFT JOIN (select 2016 as yr UNION ALL select 2017 as yr UNION ALL select 2018 as yr UNION ALL select 2019 as yr UNION ALL select 2020 as yr) as years ON po.bookingYear=years.yr
WHERE po.vendorNumber=12345 group by po.bookingYear;
```

I started out with a simple "WHERE bookingYear IN (...)", but since there are no records for the past three years, none are returned. Searching here and on Google suggested I left join a subquery like above (though probably not *exactly* like above).

I think the biggest issue here is, that I don't have NULL *values* for certain *fields* in certain years but simply *no records at all* for those years for some vendors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? My SQL has become a bit rusty it seems. Speaking of: yes: mySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right idea.  Wrong order.  The years go first:

```
SELECT years.yr, COALESCE(SUM(po.grossValue), 0)
FROM (select 2016 as yr UNION ALL select 2017 as yr UNION ALL select 2018 as yr UNION ALL select 2019 as yr UNION ALL select 2020 as yr
     ) years LEFT JOIN
     purchaseorder po
     ON po.bookingYear = years.yr AND
        po.vendorNumber = 12345 
GROUP BY years.yr;
```

Note the other changes to the query:

- The filtering on `vendorNumber` is now in the `ON` clause rather then `WHERE` clause.  In the `WHERE` clause it would turn the outer join to an inner join.
- The `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` use `years.yr`.  The value `po.bookingYear` might be `NULL`.
- I prefer `COALESCE()`, the SQL standard function, to `IFNULL()` a bespoke MySQL function.

Comment: MySQL is not the only DBMS which supports IFNULL().

Comment: @Akina . . . It is *not* a standard function.  SQL provides a nice standard function for this, `COALESCE()`.  All real databases support that.

Comment: I agreed - moreover, I use IFNULL never (you may search my answers - only one contains this functon, and it was simply copypasted from OP without edition), COALESCE only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query to generate the dates. This incurs less typing than `union all` if you have a lot of years:

```
with years as (
    select 2016 bookingYear
    union all select bookingYear + 1 from years where bookingYear < 2020 
)
select y.bookingYear, coalesce(sum(po.grossValue), 0) grossValue
from years y
left join purchaseorder po on po.bookingYear = y.bookingYear and po.vendorNumber = 12345
group by y.bookingYear
```